# Hardcode password into powershells "New-PSSession"

Tags: powershell, passwords

I have a script to get and set user's Windows environment variables on other computers for a given user.  Is it possible to hard code the password for this user so that I don't have to type it every time I run the script?

My script looks something like this:

```
$s5 = New-PSSession -computername testauto2, testauto3 -Credential
Domain\testautouser

invoke-command -session $s5[0] -scriptblock {[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("TestBrowser", "user")}
```

Comment: some hints here: http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2010/10/22/encrypting-passwords.aspx

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yep - you can totally do this as long as you are comfortable with the security implications (a PW in a file somewhere)...

Here's an example:

```
 $pw = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String <insert pw here>
 $cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "Domain\User",$pw
 $session = new-pssession -computername <computer> -credential $cred
```

Comment: Does not work.  Same password entered manually that works fine won't be accepted this way.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question but how do i execute the variable 'session'? I typed 'session' into terminal and got the message 'session not recognizible as cmdlet name'

Answer (score 9):

I've used this approach in similar situations. It's certainly not perfect, but it makes me much less nervous than hardcoding a password in a file. I read and store the password during the first run, then read from the DPAPI-encrypted file afterward. I generally run scripts from a shared location on an internal network, and store the encrypted password file in a private folder on my local machine.

```
$user = "Domain\testautouser"
$passwdFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\myscript-$user"
if ((Test-Path $passwdFile) -eq $false) {
  $cred = new-object system.management.automation.pscredential $user,
        (read-host -assecurestring -prompt "Enter a password:")
    $cred.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content $passwdFile
}
else {
  $cred = new-object system.management.automation.pscredential $user,
        (Get-Content $passwdFile | ConvertTo-SecureString)
}
```

Comment: I think this is a great addition to ease security concerns a little.

Comment: Also does not work.  Always pops up the input panel even when the file does in fact exist and contain the password.

Comment: Bunch of services and such need to be setup first and you should encrypt the password to a file and retrieve as such. This method doesn't work on default setups..